# Box.com API not returning all the list of the items from the folder

Tags: c#, box-api

I am trying to get all the file names in a specific folder in box.com using the box.com api.
It is working like charm for most of the folders. The folder with more than 1400 files it in, the objFileItems.Result.Entries.Count is returning 1000 though there are 1400 files.
How can I get it to work so that all the files are returned instead of just 1000.

```
Task<BoxFolder> boxFolder1 = objClient.FoldersManager.GetInformationAsync(id: objItem.Id);
                                boxFolder1.Wait();
                                WriteLog("Processing Folder => " + boxFolder1.Result.Name);
                                Task<BoxCollection<BoxItem>> objFileItems = objClient.FoldersManager.GetFolderItemsAsync(objItem.Id, 10000);
                                objFolderItems.Wait();
                                if (objFileItems.Result.Entries.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    List<BoxItem> objFiles = objFileItems.Result.Entries.Where(i => i.Type == "file").ToList();
                                    if (objFiles.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (BoxItem objFile in objFiles)
                                        {
                                            if (Path.GetExtension(objFile.Name).ToLower() == ".pdf")
                                            {
                                                \\Insert metadata into DB
                                            }
                                         }
```

Comment: you have to rerequest for more items.https://developer.box.com/guides/api-calls/pagination/marker-based/

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [this](https://developer.box.com/reference/get-folders-id-items/) documentation, the maximum limit for this endpoint is 1000. Therefore, you'll need to take a look at [pagination](https://developer.box.com/guides/api-calls/pagination/).